# decreasing rearrangements: why the asymmetry of measure-preserving maps?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Ryff proved in [1970](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X70900387) that the decreasing rearrangement $f^*$ of a, say, continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ admits a measure preserving map $\phi$ such that $f=f^*\circ\phi$.  In general it is impossible to find a measure-preserving map $\psi$ such that $f^*=f\circ\psi$; Ryff's counterexample was reproduced at [Existence of rearrangements of functions in $L^p([0,1])$ when given a measure preserving map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59708/existence-of-rearrangements-of-functions-in-lp0-1-when-given-a-measure-pr)  The counterexample is simple and clear, yet one would like to have a more conceptual explanation of the asymmetry between the existence of $\phi$ and the nonexistence of $\psi$.

Note that passage to the decreasing rearrangement decreases the $L^p$ norm of the derivative (whenever defined) of $f$ by the [Szegő inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szeg%C5%91_inequality). Can this be generalized to show that precomposing a function by a measure-preserving map always increases the $L^p$ norm of the derivative (whenever defined) of the function?

I noticed that in the introduction to chapter 3 in the book

Lieb, Elliott H.; Loss, Michael Analysis. Second edition. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 14. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2001

the authors mention that passage to the monotone rearrangement decreases the "kinetic energy" of a function. This may be related to the Szegő inequality, but I am still not sure whether it is true more generally that precomposing by a measure-preserving transformation always increases these norms, or only in the case of the monotone rearrangement.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your question. Could you make it more precise?

Comment: @András Bátkai Are you familiar with the notion of a decreasing rearrangement of a function?

Comment: I would say basic things I picked up at my university. I find the topic interesting but did not understand what you wanted to ask. What do you mean by "conceptual explanation"? There are many many reasons, but what is conceptual?

Comment: To give an unrealistic example, if there were a natural cohomology group that gave an obstruction to finding $\psi$, that would be a conceptual explanation. Perhaps a more reasonable one would be to ask for a suitable norm such that precomposing by a measure-preserving map would always increase the norm.